# Powershell parenthesis in pattern

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to search for a pattern in a file and change the value of the version. Here's the pattern :

```
[file: FileVersion("1.2.3.$VAR$")]
```

In my Powershell script, I have a variable with the Pattern inside :

```
$FileVersionPattern   = '[file: FileVersion("[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.$VAR$")]'
```

---

```
(Get-Content "$filePath")    -replace($FileVersionPattern, ('[file: FileVersion("' + $Major + '.' + $Minor + '.' + $Release + '.$VAR$")]'))   | Set-Content  "$filePath"
```

So the return should be `($Major = 5 $Minor = 5 $Release = 5)` :

```
[file: FileVersion("5.5.5.$VAR$")]
```

It seems that the `$VAR$` and the parenthesis is causing my script to fail.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `'[file: FileVersion("[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.$VAR$")]'` with `$VAR`? Is that a variable you're using in your pattern? If so using single quotes is going to make that a literal string.

Comment: Note that to match a `[`, you need to escape it, `\[`.

Comment: The $VAR$ is not useful for the Powershell script. I'll try with the \

Comment: Same with a dot, to match a literal `.`, you need to escape it. And you need to escape `(` and `)` and `$`. The pattern should be `'\[file: FileVersion\("[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.\$VAR\$"\)]'`

Comment: `\[file:\ FileVersion\("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.\$VAR\$"\)]`

Comment: Spaces do not have to be escaped, but I guess `[regex]::Escape` is necessary here. Anyway, it is a dupe by all means.